# Meaning of "sense" in English

Tags: word-usage

I used to use the word "sense" when I wanted to ask about the point\purpose of a particular thing (for example a book, or a game.) Is it a correct usage, though?

For example:

> What's the sense of this game? (=What I'm supposed to do in this game?)

We also can use the word "point" here. But is the word "sense" acceptable here, too?

Comment: Usually, "What is the sense of it?" means "What is its *rationality*?" As with "what is the sense of going out in the rain without a coat?" I think you mean "What is the *purpose/point* of the game?" If you ask "What is the sense of this game?" I would take it to mean that you think it is a stupid game that is not worth playing. OTOH you could ask "What is the sense of 'deaf' in 'turn a deaf ear'?" which asks for its *meaning*.

Answer (score 1):

A complex issue. I will review a few meanings of *sense*. No doubt others will be able to add more. *Point* may be used in the same way.  In many cases there is ambiguity that must be resolved by thinking of the context.

"What is the sense of ... ?" may be a rhetorical question (presupposing no sense, point or purpose) that is asked when there is no purpose or point in something.
*If the boat has a large hole, what is the sense (point) in bailing it out with a small jug? It is going to sink anyway.*

"What is the sense of this paragraph?" is most likely to be asking for a paraphrase of the main points and arguments of a paragraph of prose.
Nevertheless, the context is crucial. In speech, a sneering tone would imply that there was no sense in or point to the paracgraph. Similarly, in prose the question would be negative if it followed a negative introduction. For example, "*The described beliefs were refuted ten years ago, so what is the sense of this paragraph?*"

"What is the sense of this game?"
• may be a rhetorical question that there is no sense or point in playing it
• or it may simply be asking what is the nature of the game or what is the way it develops: is it a game of chance, skill, strategy, physical prowess, mental agility, manual dexterity etc?

"What is the sense of the water flow?" is likely asking for the general direction of the flow of water.

"What is the sense of building this machine?" may be the rhetorical usage above that is really saying there is no sense or point in building the machine, or it may be a straightforward query about the purpose of building it.

Comment: The question has been closed by those who believe the answer lies in consulting dictionaries. I answered the question because it was clear on consulting dictionaries that the ranges of meanings and usages of each word overlapped  to such an extent that anyone needing to pose such a question would inevitably not be able to extract an answer. It should be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

You could say what is the goal; the way "what is the sense of this game" reads, it feels like you are asking "what is the vibe of this game? what is the feel of it?" but I think what you are really asking is what is the goal, what is the objective. Sense is not entirely incorrect but you will probably be met with more confusion from other nonnative speakers.

Comment: Is the question about *sensibility*?